# Custom NSFormatter implementation for NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsformatter

I'm pretty new to Cocoa development, and I'm having troubles with custom NSFormatter implementation.

In my application I need to get the user's input and validate it. The input format should be something like:

hh:mm:ss:nn - where hh (hours are from 00 to 24), mm and ss (minutes and seconds from 00 to 60), and nn 
is some number ranges from 00 to 50.

If anyone knows any kind of a good source where I can find a similar problem example, or can explain me how to solve this problem I would really appreciate it!!!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I used Regex instead of formatter to validate my input.